# Calling someone with a broken SIM card?

Tags: simcard

My friend broke her (Australian Telstra pre-payed) SIM card in half just so she couldn't be contacted anymore. 
Now every time I call her it's saying 
"The number you have called is not connected. Please check the number and try again!"

I find that quite odd.

Is that the correct Telstra message that I should be getting? 
or, surely it is meant to go through to MessageBank! 
It seems more likely that message means that she has deactivated her number and got a new number.

Because I can't imagine a just a broken SIM card would terminate the phone number completely.

I can only imagine a broken SIM would behave more like a SIM that's only been removed from the hone and would go straight to Message Bank. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: Your question boils down to why did you get an error message instead of your call going to voice mail? I'm not sure if there is an infosec question here...

Answer (score 1):

You're right.

From view point of the provider, a broken SIM is as good as a good SIM in a turned-off phone, in a phone without battery, or outside of the phone. The phone won't "log in" to the network anymore with the data from the SIM, and that is all the provider can know.

Unless, of course, your friend got in contact with them and told them that it is broken. And then of course, if a replacement with the same number isn't wanted (or possible), the number will get deactivated.

Comment: So, why didn't the call go to voicemail? Why the error message?

Comment: As said, the number will be deactivated because of a manual action. The friend will have terminated the contract (or got terminated by the provider for some reason).